# send email when exception has occurred not working , using exception_notification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception-notification

I am migrating from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1, I am trying to send a email when exception is generated. I am using exception_notification gem.

My rest of the emails are working. But exception mail is not getting fired.

below are the settings in my staging.rb file.

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

and following is the code in application.rb

```
C::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email => {
    :email_prefix => "[#{Rails.env.to_s.upcase} Error] ",
    :sender_address => %{"Exception Notifier " <email_id>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{email_id}
  }
```

I am not sure why the email is not triggering, nor do i see any error. Any help would be appriciated, Thanks.

Comment: Recipients set to _String_ `"email_id"`. Looks suspicious.

Comment: That is juts a placeholder variable, i have proper email id set there

Comment: what is the version of your `exception_notification` gem ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure your app like this:

```
C::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
  :email_prefix => "[#{Rails.env.to_s.upcase} Error] ",
  :sender_address => %{"Exception Notifier " <email_id>},
  :exception_recipients => %w{email_id}
```

**Note** You have excesive `:email => {...}` declaration which is used in configuration for `exception_notifier` version `4` (see [here](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#upgrading-to-4x-version)). But you can't use version `4` of  `exception_notifier` with rails `3.1`.

I created a repository at github https://github.com/dimakura/stackoverflow-projects/tree/master/32118817-exception-notification, which is a working example. I used ruby `1.9.3`, rails `3.1.12` and `exception_notifier` `3.0.1`. I guess you are using the same gems or close to it.

**Note 2** When I added `email: {...}` to the configuration, exception messages stop to arrive.

Comment: hi dimakura, so you suggest not to add email: {...} to configuration

Comment: Yes, configure without it. I exactly reproduced your bug, by using email: {}

Answer (score 1):

move the gem configuration code to the `environment.rb` file, instead of `application.rb`